# "Archive not supported" error when trying to open .xpi file

Tags: archive

Trying open a `.xpi` file (Firefox extension) with file-roller and unrar but I obtain this error:

> Archive not supported

Why? On 11.04 I was able to open it!

Answer (score 5):

You need too use unzip for that. Install it with `sudo apt-get install unzip` if you dont have it and `file-roller` will be able to uncompress the xpi after the installation, just right click on it and select "Extract here".

You can also do it on the command line

`unzip addon-1865-latest.xpi` will uncompressed the file inside the current directory.

`zip -r <name of the addon>.xpi .` will add all the files on the current directory back to a xpi archive. ie: extract all files to the current dir `unzip addon-1865-latest.xpi`, remove original `rm addon-1865-latest.xpi`, do your modifications to the files, repack them with `zip -r addon-1865-latest.xpi .`.

Comment: ok, after my customizations to the internal file, how can I rebuild the correct package .xpi ?

Comment: added next steps to the answer, btw you don't need to repack it to use the addon, [check this](http://www.uptechtalk.com/?p=74) for further instructions. Same article [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts/73480#73480).

Comment: when i try to repack them i obtain this error: "zip error: Nothing to do! (myaddon.xpi)". I'm working in the same dir that includes all files

Comment: :S maybe a mistake, sec let me test since I am doing this by head.

Comment: sorry, faulty command, forgot a `.` its fixed now.

Comment: It works ok but is there a way to do it with file-roller?

Comment: right click, select unzip here (after you installed unzip from the command line).

Comment: or just rename it to .zip and open it with file-roller. The question in my mind is how to tell file-roller to look at the file magic and not the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up the software center and get 7zip. See if that works for you.

Comment: .xpi's are zipped folders. It could be the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. A workaround is to temporarily rename the file to .zip instead of .xpi before opening it.

It seems that the utility now fails to recognise the .xpi file type as a zip archive.

Answer (score 0):

Install assogiate in the Ubuntu Software Centre or:

`sudo apt-get install assogiate`

Run assogiate, then look for zip on the search box.
You should find: application zip zip archive

Right click on it -> Edit -> Filenames -> Add *.xpi

It should work now :)