# How to install firefox addon Skip Cert Error silently through automation

Tags: firefox, scripts, firefox-extensions, add-on

I want to install firefox addon [Skip Cert Error](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error/) to skip ssl error for my automation projects running on Linux virtual hosts. However, I want this installation of add-on to be unattended through some script.

I have followed the steps mentioned in this thread [answer by Bruno Pereira](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts), I have tried both Global and User specific method, but they don't work for me.  However, When I install the addon manually from firefox add-on page, it works fine as expected.
Any help on getting this to work or any other solution will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

wget https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/1865/addon-1865-latest.xpi
firefox -silent -install-global-extension addon-1865-latest.xpi -setDefaultBrowser www.google.es