# Deploy firefox including extensions to LiveCD

Tags: command-line, firefox, live-cd, customization, firefox-extensions

I'm working on a [customized](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) **LiveCD** and would like to **provide Firefox including a few extensions pre-installed**. The steps of LiveCD customization are done within a self-written .sh-script.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts) question where an approach for my requirement is discussed.
Following that approach, what I did then via `chroot` in path `edit/` is:

1. Download the XPI file I want to have installed.
2. Unzip it.
3. Read the extension ID in manifest.json (a string like this `'id':  '{idstring}'`).
4. Create a folder `{idstring}` in `/usr/share/mozilla/extensions` and insert all files retrieved by unzipping the XPI file.

Unfortunately, when I test the generated ISO file and run firefox, the extension is not available and is also not installed on startup of firefox.

**How can I add an extension to firefox for the LiveCD via a .sh-script?** If there are several approaches, I would prefer if the installation is already finished when running firefox on the LiveCD for the first time.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:** While after performing the procedure mentioned above the extensions are available in path `edit/usr/share/mozilla/extensions` in folder `{idstring}` and therefore should be included in the created LiveCD, I can't find them when booting from the LiveCD.
  What am I missing here?
 If you need additional information, just let me know.