# How to install extension in firefox automatically?

Tags: command-line, firefox, docker, add-on

**Hi**

I have the need to be able to install an **extension** that I made myself for **Firefox** in ubuntu but without a **graphic terminal** so I need to be able to install the extension without the need for **user interaction**

I want to do this because I am **working with dockers** and I do not have a **graphical interface** to be able to interact with my container that has the **Ubuntu system image**. And therefore I cannot use beyond commands to interact with ubuntu in my docker container.

try to use the [Firefox command:](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Mozilla/Opciones_de_linea_de_Comandos)

> firefox -install-global-extension /path/to/extension

But it also requires **user interaction** so that it can accept the installation of the extension.

I found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts) but I do not understand how to make the i**nstallation automatic** because loading the **.xpi** to the folder with the extensions does not **install in Firefox**